# "PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAlbumSyncedAlbum" not returning photos synced from Photos for Mac

Tags: ios, photos, alasset, phasset

I can't figure out how to get photos that are synced with Photos for Mac via iTunes to an iPhone to appear in PHAsset-based interactions.

I've tried every since album subtype, and it's just not working. It only shows camera roll, and various other albums created by apps that I have.

I've tried this on both 8.x and 9.x. Is there any solution?

Comment: Can you please post the actual code you are using?

Comment: Do you have solution? I also have the similar problem, and I use PHAssetCollectionSubtypeAny, but two customers report no album which sync from itunes.

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I don't think there is one.